# pythonの「send2trash」でvalueerrorが出てしまう

Tags: python

```
from send2trash import send2trash
baconFile = open('bacon.txt', 'a')
baconFile.write('nanndeerror')

baconFile.close()
send2trash('bacon.txt')
```

このコードはファイルを作ってsend2trashでファイルをゴミ箱に移動する、テストプログラムなのですが、これを実行すると、↓のようなエラーがでます。

> File
>   "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\send2trash\plat_win.py",
>   line 49, in send2trash
>       fileop.pFrom = LPCWSTR(path + '\0')
>
> ValueError: embedded null character

インターネットで色々調べてしたのですが、原因特定に至りませんでした。
このエラーの原因がわかる方がいましたらおしえていただけないでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

send2trashのバグのようです。
https://github.com/hsoft/send2trash/issues/17
gitリポジトリのHEADでは修正されているようです。
https://github.com/hsoft/send2trash/commit/5733670fc239ec82fb500051a3901e15b96f85ae

Comment: 該当ファイルのコードを編集後、動作確認。問題なく動作しました。感謝いたします。